# Can it possible to replace keyup function into button click function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

**I'm just a beginner in js. I'm trying to change the keyup function into button function. can anyone help? This is the code,**

```
<textarea id="demo"></textarea>


<script src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js'>
```

```
<script>$("#demo").bind("keyup", function() {
var text = $(this).val();
text = text.replace("good", "sweet")
text = text.replace("night", "dreams")
$(this).val(text); });</script>
```

Comment: yes, as change replace `keyup` with `click`. and if problem continues put this into `document.ready(()=>{ /*CODE*/ })`

Comment: i need to replace by button click function.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/0y84bn3v/
is this how you want?

Comment: thanks for you help bro. I got my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simple just add a button with an id or class and bind that to the event like:

```
$("#button").bind("click", function() {
  var text = $("#demo").val();
  text = text.replace("good", "sweet")
  text = text.replace("night", "dreams")
  $("#demo").val(text);
});
```

```js
$("#button").bind("click", function() {
  var text = $("#demo").val();
  text = text.replace("good", "sweet")
  text = text.replace("night", "dreams")
  $("#demo").val(text);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="demo"></textarea>
<button id="button">click me</button>
```